# The CSS style not applied until refresh

Tags: html, css, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I have a webpage with the following CSS style that overrides some higher level styles.

```
#pnlActions { 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#000),to(#000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000,#000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#000,#000);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#000,#000);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#000,#000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#000,#000);               
}
```

The odd thing is that the first time I load the page, the styles are completely ignored until I refresh the page - then the styles are applied.  Then I'll quit the browser, load the page again and the styles are no longer applied (until I refresh the page).

I can tell all this from chrome/firefox/ie browser tools.

I am at a complete loss to explain why this is happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: There's probably Javascript or an extension overriding the styles.

Comment: Is anything being cached?

Comment: post the whole code! no can answer perfectly your mistake by just looking css!

Comment: I had the same kind of issue.  It was my JavaScript so I put a timeout function set to execute 3 seconds after the page was loaded and it worked everytime since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the page with Chrome DevTools closed, open DevTools, then refresh the page, and you have the [setting](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/settings) "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" checked, this could explain your experience.

Answer (score 7):

A couple of years later, but this is how I solved it.

For some reason having the STYLE inside the HEAD tag (Internal CSS) was only working after a refresh.

But adding it as a LINK (External CSS) solved it. Now it works from the first run.

Inside the CSS I added !IMPORTANT to the styles because I needed to override some other elements, just like the OP.

For those who have doubts on how to add Internal or Extenal CSS, please check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, put all custom initial css in a file and import it via HEAD to be applied when the page is refreshed...thank you !

Comment: Your answer still useful in 2023

Answer (score 4):

Try appending the following php code to your .css file in the header. Your file must have the extension of .php for this to work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="your.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

That will rule out caching of the style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you don't have content being added inside your <head> before the reference to your stylesheet.

I had this exact same problem on my Win7 box with IE9; that is, my styles were not being applied until I did a refresh.  On my XP box with IE8 the problem did not occur; the styles were applied on initial load.

Additional info, may be helpful:
Being new to master pages, I was following along "Beginning ASP.Net 4".  The example has you add a ContentPlaceHolder in the <head> just before the link to your stylesheet (pg. 200, step 4).  The example CPH is empty.  Then they have you add the asp:Content ID="Content1"... to your ASPX on pg. 203.  I put 'Content1' inside this tag, which put 'Content1' before the stylesheet link in the browser output.  This was not in the instructions, I was seeing if it would display in the browser (it does).  I had been refreshing all along, so the apply-stylesheet-only-on-refresh issue did not appear until much later.  Removing 'Content1' on my ASPX fixed the problem -- maybe some other guru can tell us why IE9 (but not IE8) stops processing <head> content when it encounters a problem on initial load, but not on refresh.

Hope this fixes your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this same exact issue.

My code looked like this while I was getting the error: (Simplified to leave out -webkit -moz etc)

```
<div style="width: 100%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%), url('relativePathToImg.png') repeat 0 0;">
```

What I did was use the chrome dev tools, inspected the div then selected the "Computed" tab, not the "Styles" tab. I noticed that chrome computed the css as this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.701961) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%), url(http://mywebsite.com/);
```

For unknown reasons the relative url was translated into the sites root url, thus the css was looking for an image at the wrong url. I then replaced the "relativePathToImg.png" with the absolute path to the image. This fixed the problem for me.

I noticed you don't explicitly list an image in your code above however you said styles are applied elsewhere. Take a look at the "computed" tab in the dev tools and see what really is going on.